# Amazon Pay Integration in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-pay

I am developing an demo application to integrate Amazon Pay In android application. Is there any proper documentation for the same. Thanks in advance

Comment: refer this github link https://github.com/amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-java

Answer (score 0):

For using Amazon Pay in a mobile app, I'd recommend you to create a (or re-use an existing) web-based Amazon Pay integration as described in the [official documentation](https://pay.amazon.com/us/developer/documentation). For most scenarios the "One-time payments" guide will be the integration guide you want to refer to. You would simply call this web page then from the Android app (or iOS app, or whatever) and send the buyer back to the app after the payment has been completed.

As the integration is independent from Android in this scenario, you can of course use any programming language you prefer. Using PHP, Java, C# (or other .NET languages), Ruby or Python is recommended though as there are officially supported SDKs available for those.

For other "in-app" integration options, you should contact Amazon Pay directly.